# Why are many of my prisoners staying in their holding cell?

Tags: prison-architect

Although there is plenty of space for the 170 prisoners in my prison (capacity: 210), the prisoners stay in holding cells instead and leave many individual cells completely unoccupied. I can tell individual prisoners to go to unoccupied cells, but a day or two later, the prisoners end up back in the holding cells.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

All rooms are complete (enclosed, have toilet and bed) and range in quality from 3-10, with an average around 6-7.

Since the room quality feature just came out in Alpha-33 (my version), I wonder if it has something to do with that.  It's hard to tell whether this problem is a bug or a feature which I haven't learned about yet!

Comment: have you by accident designated the cell block 'staff only'? or designated it to a prisoner category that is different from the population in your holding cell?

Comment: Or even made the cell block for specific types of prisoners only? If you have beds in your holding cell then remove them.

Comment: Try deleting the holding cell (the room type only, don't demolish the building!) and see if they go to the cells. If they don't then there's something preventing them such as the quality of cell they deserve or one of the other things Sergii and Mattr have mentioned.

Comment: Screenshots of your prison in normal and deployment view would be really helpful if you could [edit] your question to include them

Comment: There are 2 bugs in the database from Alpha 33 and Alpha 34 that mention the same problem but have no details on any resolution.

Comment: No cell block was designated "staff only". Several blocks were "shared". Beds were in the holding cell, so I'll remove them and try again soon. @Rory: could you link to the bugs? Thanks!

Comment: @jvriesem [prison architect bug tracker](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/).  The screenshots of your prison would really help!

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the fact that each of your cells' living quality is above that which the prisoner deserves. Occasionally they will occupy a nice room when they don't deserve it, but most of the time they will just default to the holding cell. Since the holding cell does not have a room quality, they plop themselves en masse there. This tends to start fights, creating this nasty self-perpetuating cycle.

If you want to resolve this issue for the time being, remove the holding cell designation (click 'Rooms' and right click/drag to remove the room designation) or create a whole bunch of cells with a room quality of 0.

Comment: Really?  I couldn't find any mention of this in the bug database and in alpha-34a (compile Jun 25 2015) for me holding cells are not given a room quality number (only cells are).

Comment: I haven't seen it in the bug database either, but did see a comment on the [Cells](http://prison-architect.wikia.com/wiki/Cell) page on the wiki (scroll down almost to the bottom for a question from 2013 that was fully explained just yesterday.

Comment: I think this was mentioned in alpha video when room quality was introduced, and the threshold is 2 - i.e. prisoners can take rooms that are +2 to what they deserve, but otherwise they will stay at 0 (which is the holding cell). Maybe the OP could test this on his prison by adding 0, 1 & 2 quality cells to his prison